# Why is Urdu font being rendered in reverse?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char

Actually, I want to display some Urdu text, but since it's read from right to left. It's showing in reverse.

Hence, I reversed the string and tried to display it. But it was wrong. As the reversed string of Urdu text was wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the code? And expected as well as actual output?

Comment: Wild guess: you are reversing bytes, but the text is in UTF-something and has some multi-byte characters.

Comment: Text in variable should not be reverse at all. It doesn't meter is is LTR o RTL language. Sequence of characters in string variable represents order o of reading not displaying. Then rendering software is able to detect that characters in string contain unicode characters with different direction and places the it desired order. This gives funny effect when you mix langues with different reading directions (English and Urdu for example), when you move text cursor it can jump between languages borders.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: It seems like your are using your own printing code. In this case you have to draw Urdu from right to left. Trying to somehow draw it from left to right will bring you into madness... Make a Urdu detector and choose the right drawing function.

Comment: To help you with your own printing code of your own text you could add RTL/LTR hidden codes that you could detect in your printer code. It is slightly easier than recognising every RTL subset of unicode. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

Comment: If the string is unicode wchar then I would expect that to produce a readable result, though not great. If the string is actually codepage or utf-8 bytes then in reversing the string you need to keep runs of bytes that represent one character together in the same order, and swap the order of those runs.